# Clojure can't pass list to a function Error PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

Tags: list, clojure, mergesort

I have a few functions that deal with lists. I have an even function which accepts a list parameter and gets the even indexes of the list. The odd function does the same thing but with odd indexes. I also have another function that merges two sorted lists called merge-list that takes two lists as parameters.

The problem is with the function I am writing now: merge-sort.

Here is what I have:

```
(defn merge-sort [lis]
    (if (empty? (rest lis))
        lis
        (merge-list (merge-sort (odd(lis))) (merge-sort (even(lis))))))))
```

For some reason I keep getting the error

`java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn`

I can pass the odd function rest lis like this `(odd(rest lis))` (same with even). It runs fine but that obviously doesn't give me the solution I want.

I'm very new to Clojure so any tips would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why did you edit your code out? Now nobody can learn from your experience. I'd edit it back in, but maybe you have a reason.

Comment: Could you post your code?  It's hard to tell exactly what you're doing incorrectly if we can't see your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(odd lis)` and `(even lis)`, not `(odd (lis))`. You want to pass it as a parameter, not call it as a function and then pass the result of that.

Answer (score 3):

When the Clojure compiler encounters a list, it looks at the head of the list for a function or macro to invoke.

The error message "FooClass cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn" usually means that you have an instance of FooClass in "function position" (the head of a list) which is neither a function nor a macro.

Often this is caused by a syntax error or a buggy macro. If, as amalloy suggests, you are wrapping your list argument in parentheses, then that is the problem.

Comment: He used to have the code included next to the question, and then for some reason (apparently after my answer and before yours) he edited it out.

Comment: Sorry about that I put it back. Thanks for your help!